# Latex Change Font Size - Awesome Source CV

Tags: latex, font-awesome

I'm using [this Latex template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-source-cv/wrdjtkkytqcw) for my resume and I'd like to shrink the font size of the body text to fit more information but I'm not sure how to do so.

I'm not familiar with using Latex packages and I didn't see a font size number I could easily change; does anyone know what I can try? Here is some truncated code for the formatting class.

```
% This work consists of the files awesome-source-cv.cls 

\ProvidesClass{yaac-another-awesome-cv}[2018/07/19  v1.9.2 'YAAC: Another Awesome CV' Class]

\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\newif\if@showLinks   \@showLinksfalse

\DeclareOption{green}{
  \def\@green{green}
}

\DeclareOption{red}{
  \def\@red{red}
}

\DeclareOption{indigo}{
  \def\@indigo{indigo}
}
\DeclareOption{orange}{
  \def\@orange{orange}
}

\DeclareOption{monochrome}{
  \def\@monochrome{monochrome}
}

\DeclareOption{localFont}{
  \def\@local{local}
}

\DeclareOption{alternative}{
  \def\@alternative{alternate}
}

\DeclareOption{showLinks}{ \@showLinkstrue}

\ProcessOptions

% Dependences
%A Few Useful Packages
\RequirePackage[english,french]{babel}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}                                    % for loading fonts
\RequirePackage{url,parskip}        % other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{fullpage}
\RequirePackage[margin=0.75cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{longtable}  
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}


\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E9}{\'{e}}
% Define default accent colors
\definecolor{basecolor}{HTML}{000066}       %BLUE

\ifundef{\@green} {
  \ifundef{\@red} {
    \ifundef{\@indigo}{
      \ifundef{\@orange} {
        \ifundef{\@monochrome} {}
        { \definecolor{basecolor}{HTML}{000000}}
      }
      { \definecolor{basecolor}{HTML}{e68a00} }
    }
    { \definecolor{basecolor}{rgb}{0.2, 0.07, 0.48} }
  }
  { \definecolor{basecolor}{HTML}{b30000} }     %RED
}
{ \definecolor{basecolor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.38} }

\definecolor{darkGrey}{HTML}{989898}

\colorlet{linkcolor}{basecolor}
\colorlet{accentcolor}{linkcolor!90}
\colorlet{symbolcolor}{linkcolor!85}

% Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
%\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

\if@showLinks
  \hypersetup{%
    breaklinks
  }%
\else
  \hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    breaklinks
  }%
\fi

% Setup fancyhdr package
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhfoffset{0em}
% Remove head rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%\pagestyle{empty}                         % non-numbered pages
%\font\fb=''[cmr10]''                      % for use with \LaTeX command

% Setup CV sections
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{2pt}

% Configure list
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\faAngleRight, nosep, leftmargin=2.0em} 
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\faAngleRight, nosep, leftmargin=1.5em} 

% Setup Array : new column type
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\hfill}m{#1}}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

% Setup fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%

% Define font to use according to localFont option
\ifundef{\@local}
{
  %\setmainfont[BoldFont = Helvetica Neue, ItalicFont=Helvetica Neue Thin Italic ,SmallCapsFont = Helvetica Neue Light]{Helvetica Neue Thin}
  \setmainfont{Source Sans Pro Light}[
    BoldFont = SourceSansPro-Regular, 
    ItalicFont= Source Sans Pro Light Italic]
}
{
  \setmainfont{SourceSansPro-Light}[
    Path = fonts/, 
    BoldFont = SourceSansPro-Regular, 
    ItalicFont = SourceSansPro-LightIt]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go a bit smaller if you replace `\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}` with

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,9pt]{article}
```

in your class. Or even tinier:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,8pt]{extarticle}
```

Comment: Thanks! As a follow up, the second command changes all the text to 8pt including my headers/section titles, but I'd prefer the smaller text just for the body text. What would you suggest I look for to distinguish size between the types of text?

Comment: You could probably just switch to a smaller font size at the start of your document, maybe something like `\footnotesize`. However your question only contains the class and no test document, so no headings or anything to test.